# Turn element into a card

Tags: css

I need to turn an `div` element into some sort of a "Card". I.e. all children should become non-selectable, non-clickable, but still visible. I tried `user-select: none` on the div, but it does not affect all the children.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can post here? Or a sample/reference that you are looking at?

Comment: add an overlay above everything

Comment: `user-select: none; pointer-events: none;` First is for non selectable and the other one is for non-clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a transparent layer on top of it, just like this :

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.elememt-1 {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: orange;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
      <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
      <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
   <div class="elememt-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does `width: 100%` works here? Is it 100% of something referenced by an id that preceedes `::after`?

Comment: @exebook yes bro. You got the point. If you set width or height of an element wiht position: relative, then if you set width 100% and height 100% to its children (::before or ::after in this case play the same role as child), its dimension will auto fill same size with its parent. U understand ?